# How to use svg icon in every slice of pie chart of zingchart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add svg icon in every value slice of **pie-chart** like show in this image.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9PHl.png)

I have search too much on google about but i can't, can someone help me. this code which i am trying..

```js
var myConfig = {
  "type": "ring",
  "plot": {
   "refAngle": 320,
   "slice": 100
  },
  "legend": {
   "align":'center',
   "item": {
    "height": "40px",
    "padding":'10px 40px', 
   },
   "marker": {
    "width":'40px',
    "height":'40px', 
   },
  },
  "series": [{
   "values": [38],
   "text": "Instagram",
   "background-color": "#C32AA3 #FFDC7D",
  },
  {
   "values": [69],
   "text": "Pinterest",
   "background-color": "#BD081C",
  },   
  ]
 };

 zingchart.render({
  id: 'pie-chart-2',
  data: myConfig,
  height: 400,
  width: "100%"
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>
  <div id='pie-chart-2'></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself, please show us.

Comment: i'm adding this code to "series":[ { 
"values": [38], 
"images"["src":"images/instagram.svg", ]
 },]
but this is not working i cant understand...

Comment: Most likely it's not working because you haven't got the right path for the images, is the images included in your solution, and is the path correctly?

Comment: "yes" the path is correct because other images are working well. but when i use this code then the chart also not showing...

Answer (score 0):

yes, this can be done and this code generate the pie chart with icon inside every slice of chart.

```js
var aPalette = [
 '#F6842E', '#FBAC33', '#8AC340', '#46B863', '#41BC9F', '#29C2EC', 
 '#387EC3', '#5253A3', '#764199', '#962871', '#C87F8A', '#F14F42'
];
var aIcons = [
 'ic00', 'ic01', 'ic02', 'ic03', 'ic04', 'ic05', 
 'ic06', 'ic07', 'ic08', 'ic09', 'ic10', 'ic11' 
];
var aText = [
 'Lorem ipsum<br>dolor sit amet,<br>consectetur<br>adipiscing elit.', 'Lorem ipsum<br>dolor sit amet,<br>consectetur<br>adipiscing elit.',
 'Lorem ipsum<br>dolor sit amet,<br>consectetur<br>adipiscing elit.', 'Lorem ipsum<br>dolor sit amet,<br>consectetur<br>adipiscing elit.',
 'Lorem ipsum<br>dolor sit amet,<br>consectetur<br>adipiscing elit.', 'Lorem ipsum<br>dolor sit amet,<br>consectetur<br>adipiscing elit.',
 'Lorem ipsum<br>dolor sit amet,<br>consectetur<br>adipiscing elit.', 'Lorem ipsum<br>dolor sit amet,<br>consectetur<br>adipiscing elit.',
 'Lorem ipsum<br>dolor sit amet,<br>consectetur<br>adipiscing elit.', 'Lorem ipsum<br>dolor sit amet,<br>consectetur<br>adipiscing elit.',
 'Lorem ipsum<br>dolor sit amet,<br>consectetur<br>adipiscing elit.', 'Lorem ipsum<br>dolor sit amet,<br>consectetur<br>adipiscing elit.'
];
var aTooltipText = [
 'Lorem ipsum', 'Lorem ipsum', 'Lorem ipsum', 'Lorem ipsum', 'Lorem ipsum', 'Lorem ipsum',
 'Lorem ipsum', 'Lorem ipsum', 'Lorem ipsum', 'Lorem ipsum', 'Lorem ipsum', 'Lorem ipsum'
];

var render = function() {

 var cdata = {
  resources : [
   {
    type : 'css',
    url : 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2'
   }
  ],
  type : 'pie',
  plotarea : {
   margin : 0
  },
  scaleR : {
   aperture : parseInt($('#a').val(), 10),
   refAngle : parseInt($('#ra').val(), 10)
  },
  plot : {
   detach : false,
   borderWidth : 0,
   borderColor : '#fff',
   slice : '19%',
   pieTransform : 'fold=60',
   hoverState : {
    visible : false
   }
  },
  series:[]
 };

 if ($('#an').val() !== '-1') {
  cdata['plot'].animation = {
   speed : 200,
   method : 0,
   effect : parseInt($('#an').val(), 10),
   sequence : parseInt($('#s').val(), 10)
  };
 }

 var items = parseInt($('#n').val(), 10);

 for (var i=0;i<items;i++) {
  var no = i+1;
  cdata['series'].push({
   values : [1],
   tooltipText : aTooltipText[i],
   dataNo : ((no<=9)?'0'+no:no),
   valueBox : [
    {
     width : 48,
     height : 48,
     placement : 'fixed=90%;75%',
     borderRadius : 23,
     borderWidth : 0,
     fontSize : 6,
     shadow : false,
     color : '#4B4B4B',
     decimals : 0,
     fontFamily : '"Exo 2"',
     text : '<span style="font-size:27px">%data-no</span><br><span style="font-size:9px;color:' + aPalette[i] + '">\u2002\u2002OPTION</span>'
    },
    {
     width : 24,
     height : 24,
     placement : 'fixed=80%;6',
     backgroundColor : 'none',
     shadow : false,
     backgroundImage : ICONS24[aIcons[i]],
     backgroundRepeat : 'no-repeat',
     text : ' '
    },
    {
     align : 'left',
     placement : 'fixed=55%;50%',
     backgroundColor : 'none',
     shadow : false,
     fontSize : 9,
     text : aText[i]
    }
   ],
   backgroundColor : aPalette[i],
   gradientColors : ['#eee', '#eee', aPalette[i], aPalette[i]].join(' '),
   gradientStops : [0.001, 0.30, 0.31, 0.35, 0.36, 0.5].join(' ')
  });
 }

 zingchart.render({
  id : 'zc',
  width : 600,
  height : 600,
  output : 'svg',
  data : cdata,
  events : {
   animation_end : function(p) {
    if ($('#an').val() !== '-1') { 
     addElements(p);
    }
   },
   load : function(p) {
    if ($('#an').val() === '-1') { 
     addElements(p);
    }
   }
  }
 });
}

WebFont.load({
 google : {
  families: ['Exo 2']
 },
 active : function() {

  $('#r').click(function() {
   render();
  });
  render();

  var _cpoint_ = function(iX, iY, iR, iAngle) {
   return [iX + iR*Math.cos(iAngle*2*Math.PI/360), iY + iR*Math.sin(iAngle*2*Math.PI/360)];
  }

  window.addElements = function(p) {
   var iPlots = zingchart.exec(p.id, 'getplotlength');
   var aObjects = [], oInfo;
   for (var i=0;i<iPlots;i++) {
    oInfo = zingchart.exec(p.id, 'getobjectinfo', {
     object : 'node',
     plotindex : i,
     nodeindex : 0
    });
    var iSlice = oInfo.size * oInfo.slice;
    var aCP = _cpoint_(oInfo.x, oInfo.y, (iSlice + oInfo.size)/2 - 4, oInfo.angleStart);
    
    aObjects.push({
     id : 'sh'+i,
     anchor : 'c',
     x : aCP[0],
     y : aCP[1],
     width : (oInfo.size - iSlice) - 2,
     height : 10,
     backgroundColor : '#eee',
     angle : oInfo.angleStart,
     gradientColors : 'rgba(0,0,0,0) rgba(0,0,0,0) rgba(100,100,100,0.5) rgba(100,100,100,0.4) rgba(100,100,100,0.3) rgba(100,100,100,0.2) rgba(100,100,100,0.1) rgba(100,100,100,0)',
     gradientStops : '0.01 0.5 0.51 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 0.99'
    });
   }

   aObjects.push(
    {
     x : oInfo.x,
     y : oInfo.y,
     width : 1.75*oInfo.slice*oInfo.size,
     fontFamily : '"Exo 2"',
     fontSize : 14,
     align : 'center',
     fontWeight : 600,
     color : '#000',
     anchor : 'c',
     text : 'INFOGRAPHIC<br>TEMPLATE'
    }
   );

   zingchart.exec(p.id, 'addobject', {
    type : 'label',
    data : aObjects
   });
  };

 }

});
```

```css
body { 
  margin:10px;
  padding:10px; 
}

*, input, button, select, textarea, label {
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode',Monaco,Tahoma,Verdana,Arial;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      zingchart.MODULESDIR = "https://cdn.zingchart.com/modules/";
    </script>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
      crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfont.js"></script>
    <script src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/374756/icons.js'></script>
  </head>
 <body>
    
    <script>
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        $(document.body).append('<iframe style="border:0px;position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;width:270px;height:480px;" src="https://codepen.io/zingchart/full/ef639d5ca7dd69ae067720228a01d542"></iframe>');
      }, 2500);
    </script>
    
  <div style="padding:5px;">
 <select id="n">
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12" selected="selected">12</option>
 </select> elements, 
 <select id="a">
  <option value="180">180</option>
  <option value="270">270</option>
  <option value="360" selected="selected">360</option>
 </select> aperture, starting at 
 <select id="ra">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="45">45</option>
  <option value="90">90</option>
  <option value="135">135</option>
  <option value="180">180</option>
  <option value="225">225</option>
  <option value="270" selected="selected">270</option>
  <option value="315">315</option>
 </select> degrees, with
 <select id="an">
  <option value="-1">no animation</option>
  <option value="0">effect 0</option>
  <option value="1" selected="selected">effect 1</option>
  <option value="2">effect 2</option>
  <option value="3">effect 3</option>
  <option value="4">effect 4</option>
 </select>, 
 <select id="s">
  <option value="0">non-sequenced</option>
  <option value="1" selected="selected">in sequence</option>
 </select>
 <button id="r">Render</button>
</div>
    
  <div id="zc"></div>
 
  </body>
</html>
```